# Outlook Tasks in Microsoft Graph

Tags: outlook-restapi

I am interested to to use Outlook Tasks. I know that is it available in Microsoft Graph Beta (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/compare-graph-outlook)

Does anyone know that when will it be released?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could post the question and feedback to Official under the article you provided directly. 
[image]

Link : [A New Feedback System Is Coming to learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/teamblog/a-new-feedback-system-is-coming-to-docs)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the Outlook tasks API has been deprecated and is superseded by the [ToDo API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/todo-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) :/

[image]